# Is it OK to replace only one baseboard thermostat?

Tags: heating, baseboard

Trying to help my folks figure out what to do with heat in their house. Two story home in cold climate, 30 year old electric baseboard heaters.

Can I replace only the living room thermostat - or do I need to do all at once?

Comment: Why would replace the thermostat ?  Is it faulty ?

Comment: I've answered your question but I feel like there's another question or plan in the background which you might want to also post. If the goal is to reduce heating costs, a more intelligent thermostat can help a little, but it's going to be on the order of a few percent at best. Almost certainly the better way to go will be by adding mini splits.

Answer (score 1):

Go for it. One of my friends has had to replace one of their baseboard thermostats twice while the other two are the original 1980s units. Unless this is a very weird system, there's no connection between the thermostats. Be aware that these will be 'line voltage' thermostats, so if you're thinking of using a smart thermostat it almost certainly won't work.